# How to do aggreagtion in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do some aggregation in my file.

Eg: My file contain Date, Grade,Sale columns. For a specific date, if same grade occurs more than once I need to aggregate the sale value.

Input

```
Date       Grade    Sale
1/08/2019   Diesel   1000
1/08/2019   Petrol    500
1/08/2019   Diesel    2000
2/08/2019   Diesel    300
```

Output

```
Date       Grade    Sale
1/08/2019  Diesel   3000
1/08/2019  Petrol   500
2/08/2019  Diesel   300

df= df.append(data) 
df = aggregate_samegrade_sales(df)

def aggregate_samegrade_sales(data):
..??
```

How can I read each row from the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
(df.groupby(['Date','Grade'])
   .agg({'Sale':'sum'})
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: Then finally I need to write the output in an excel .Will this groupby affect the rows writing to an excel?    df.to_excel(writer, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Grade', 'Sales'], sheet_name='sales')

Comment: I have added `reset_index()` at the end for your excel output

Comment: .agg function adding the values at end like string merge. eg 120 and 500 . I expect it to be 620. But the output is like 120500.

Comment: That's because the  `Sale` column  is of String type instead of numeric. Add before the code `df['Sale'] = df['Sale'].astype('float')`